# Multiline equations when converting from jupyter notebook to tex

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pandoc, nbconvert

I'm using `nbconvert` to convert from Jupyter notebook containing MathJax equations to tex files. One problem is that multi-line equations which contain alignment, i.e.

```
$$
/begin{align}
...
/end{align}
$$
```

are converted in tex to

```
\[
\begin{align}
...
\end{align}
\]
```

And it yield a tex bug: `unexpected close display math ] after \begin{document}

Comment: Using a recent pandoc version, you can wrap it in [code block with raw attribute](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute)